# The meaning of もらう in this sentence

Tags: nuances

- **それは、気をつけてもらいたいな。**

1. I'm not sure what 気をつけてもらいたい means here.
2. I think some parts are omitted but I can't seem to figure that out. I think the meaning is "I want you to be safe for me."

- Is the meaning the same if you just make it into 気をつけてください？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does essentially mean the same thing as `気をつけてください`, just with different nuance.

It does literally mean something like "I want you to be safe for me." But I would say "I want you to be *careful* for me" would be a better translation. Maybe they don't care whether you stay safe or not, they just don't want you to total their car that you're borrowing.

It's not as polite as `気をつけてください`. It sounds like you are speaking to someone who is lesser than you (or perhaps a close friend). I also feel it implies you think the person might not be careful if you don't specifically warn them to be.

The meaning of もらう specifically in this sentence is to "have X done for me". It is used after the て form of a verb to indicate what is being done. [Further reading](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%86-te-morau-%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84-te-moraitai-meaning/)

Comment: If the sentence is complete, would it be something like 私は君に気をつけてもらいたい？

Comment: Yes, that's right (though including the 私は part would sound a bit robotic, it's grammatically correct)